# Refactor callback code into async / await

Tags: node.js, async-await, loopbackjs, html-to-pdf

I have a node.js / (express based) loopback.js app, with a PDF service, which uses HtmlToPDF, to generate PDFs.

Some code:

**services/pdf.js**

```
exports.PDF = function(options, cb) {
  // ...
  var htmlToPDF = new HTMLToPDF({
    // ... options
  });

  function sendBackFile(outputPath, cb) {
    fs.readFile(outputPath, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {cb(err)}
      var contentDisposition = 'attachment; filename=' + filename + '.pdf';
      cb(null, data, 'application/pdf', contentDisposition, 'SAMEORIGIN');
    })
  }
  // start / stop Xvfb code ...
  htmlToPDF.build(function (err) {
    if (err) {cb(err)};
    // read the file and send it back
    sendBackFile(outputPath, cb)
  });
}
```

For different types of PDFs, I have different templates. (for a different name, outputPath, template etc. per type)

```
exports.invetory = function(html, cb) {
  exports.PDF({
    html: html
  }, cb);
}
```

And here is an example, how I use the service from the code.

**models/inventory.js**

```
  Inventory.pdf = (id, next) => {
    pdf.inventory('yo', next);
  }
```

Break down

1. PDF service is imported to code, and the inventory template is called
2. Inventory template calls the PDF service
3. PDF service starts a htmlToPDF instance, a PDF is created and saved as a file.
4. the file is read from the disk, and the API sends it back.

***The question***

I try to make my `Inventory.pdf` function to async / await aware. But if I do

```
  Inventory.pdf = async (id, next) => {
    return await pdf.inventory('yo', next);
  }
```

next, (the callback function) will be *undefined*, that's OK, but how should I change the PDF service, to make it work with both async calls, and with the old callback way. (I have many old template function in the code). Any suggestion is more than welcome.

Comment: You need to have a `return` in `if (err) {cb(err)}`: `if (err) {return cb(err)}` without it the rest of the callback will run. And `cb` will be called twice.

Answer (score 2):

async/ await will only work with promises. So your inventory function will need to become a promise. I attempted to un-nest your functions with the hopes of making it easier to read. I don't have the full codebase but hopefully the general idea comes across. Some vars etc. may be missing as a result.

```
// Build HTML to PDF
exports.htmlToPDF = function() {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    let htmlToPDFData;

    try {
      htmlToPDFData = await htmlToPDF.build();
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err);
      return;
    }

    resolve(htmlToPDFData);
  });
};

// Read data from a file
exports.sendBackFile = function(outputPath) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    let fileData;

    try {
      fileData = await fsReadFile(outputPath, "utf8");
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err);
      return;
    }

    resolve(fileData);
  });
};

exports.PDF = function(options) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    // ...
    const htmlToPDF = new HTMLToPDF({
      // ... options
    });

    let backFileData;
    let htmlToPDFData;

    try {
      backFileData = await exports.sendBackFile(outputPath);
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err);
    }

    const contentDisposition = `attachment; filename=${filename}.pdf`;

    // Assuming this function is not a promise we just call it. Originally this was one of the callback functions.
    callWhateverFunctionWeNeedTo(
      null,
      backFileData,
      "application/pdf",
      contentDisposition,
      "SAMEORIGIN"
    );

    // start / stop Xvfb code ...
    try {
      htmlToPDFData = await exports.htmlToPDF();
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err);
    }

    // Read the file and send it back
    try {
      await exports.sendBackFile(htmlToPDFData);
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
  });
};

// Call inventory
exports.invetory = function(html) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      await exports.PDF({ html });
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err);
    }

    resolve();
  });
};

Inventory.pdf = async (id, next) => {
  try {
    await pdf.inventory("yo");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }

  next();
};
```